# Does the equivalent of "aws deploy push" in PowerShell exist?

Tags: powershell, aws-code-deploy

I'm reading through the CodeDeploy reference docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/AWS_CodeDeploy_cmdlets.html); and can't find the equivalent of `aws deploy push` command to send up a new version of my application to s3 to be ready for deployment.

Do I need to just zip these files myself and send them to s3 with the other PowerShell tools instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `push` is not a single API call, but rather a multistep operation, the simplest way to automate it in a powershell script is to literally put the command in the script

```
aws deploy push
```

You may need to make sure the aws executable is on your path.

Comment: This also works well: 

Compress-Archive -Force -Path $CodeDeployProjectPath\* -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath c:\temp\HelloWorld_App.zip

    Write-S3Object -BucketName bucket-name -Key HelloWorld_App.zip -File c:\temp\HelloWorld_App.zip